# rubik's cube, thick lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am using \ usepackage {rubikcube}, but the cube grid lines are very thick, How to make it thinner.

Thank you very much for your answers

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,
 bottom=1.5cm ,headheight=16pt]{geometry}

 \usepackage{rubikcube}
 %\usepackage{rubikrotation,rubikpatterns,rubiktwocube}% Related packages
 % Colores
 \definecolor{A}{RGB}{255,255,0}
 \definecolor{V}{RGB}{0,255,0}
 \definecolor{C}{RGB}{0,0,255}
 \definecolor{N}{RGB}{255,165,0}
 \definecolor{Bl}{RGB}{255,255,255}
 \definecolor{R}{RGB}{255,0,0}
 \definecolor{X}{RGB}{192,192,192}
 \definecolor{_}{RGB}{65,65,65}
 \begin{document}
 \RubikCubeGreyAll
 \RubikFaceUp WWW
  WYW
  WWW
  \RubikFaceFront WYW XXXXXX
  \RubikFaceRight YYY XXXXXX
  \RubikFaceBack  WYW XXXXXX
  \RubikFaceLeft  YYY XXXXXX
  \ShowCube{1.5cm}{0.3}{\DrawRubikFaceUpSide}

   %.......
  \RubikCubeGreyAll
  \RubikFaceUp WWW
   WYW
   WWW      
  \RubikFaceFront YYY XXXXXX
  \RubikFaceRight WYY XXXXXX
  \RubikFaceBack  WYW XXXXXX
  \RubikFaceLeft  YYW XXXXXX
  \RubikSidebarWidth{0.15}
  \RubikSidebarLength{1}
  \RubikSidebarSep{0.2}
  \ShowCube{1.5cm}{0.3}{\DrawRubikFaceUpSide}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the line widths are hard coded in the style file to be `ultra thick`. This means that you can adjust the line width by redefining `ultra thick`. Most likely you do not want to do that globally, but in a group, hence `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,
 bottom=1.5cm ,headheight=16pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{rubikcube}
%\usepackage{rubikrotation,rubikpatterns,rubiktwocube}% Related packages
% Colores
\definecolor{A}{RGB}{255,255,0}
\definecolor{V}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\definecolor{C}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{N}{RGB}{255,165,0}
\definecolor{Bl}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{R}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{X}{RGB}{192,192,192}
\definecolor{_}{RGB}{65,65,65}
\begin{document}
 \RubikCubeGreyAll
 \RubikFaceUp WWW
 WYW
 WWW
 \RubikFaceFront WYW XXXXXX
 \RubikFaceRight YYY XXXXXX
 \RubikFaceBack  WYW XXXXXX
 \RubikFaceLeft  YYY XXXXXX
 \begingroup
 \tikzset{ultra thick/.style={line width=0.6pt}}%
 \ShowCube{1.5cm}{0.3}{\DrawRubikFaceUpSide}
 \endgroup

  %.......
 \RubikCubeGreyAll
 \RubikFaceUp WWW
  WYW
  WWW      
 \RubikFaceFront YYY XXXXXX
 \RubikFaceRight WYY XXXXXX
 \RubikFaceBack  WYW XXXXXX
 \RubikFaceLeft  YYW XXXXXX
 \RubikSidebarWidth{0.15}
 \RubikSidebarLength{1}
 \RubikSidebarSep{0.2}
 \begingroup
 \tikzset{ultra thick/.style={line width=0.8pt}}%
 \ShowCube{1.5cm}{0.3}{\DrawRubikFaceUpSide}
 \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the upper example the line width is set to `0.6pt`, in the lower to `0.8pt`, you can adjust these values at will.